# Zend php set distinct in query

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

how to stop to show duplicate value using zend query pls suggest

```
 public function getProductCategoryById($id) {
        $where = array(
            "product_category_id = ?" => $id
        );
        $result = $this->_db_table->fetchRow($where);
//        print_r($result);die;
        if (!$result) {

            return false;
        }
        $product_category = new Application_Model_ProductCategories($result);
        return $product_category;
    }
```

I am new zend user Iam confuse how to use distinct value in zend pls take a look my code and do changes

Pls assist

Answer (score 1):

Use distinct

```
$select = $this->select()
              ->distinct()
              ->where('product_category_id = ?', $id);
```

Comment: Where is your select Query?Add more details.

Comment: in my above code fetching all distinct rows values where product_category_id = 44 something

Comment: also your code  says Call to undefined method Application_Model_ProductCategoriesMapper::select()

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$select = $this->select()
         ->distinct()
         ->from($this)
         ->where ('product_category_id = ?', $id);
         ->anyrestconditions()
;
$result = $this->getAdapter->fetchAll($select);
```